# Don't allow the 2 videos to play simultaneously

Tags: javascript, function

I am posting two videos in .webm format. Both should not be able to play simultaneously, ie once you start one video, you cannot start the other one -unless the first one is paused. How do I solve that?

```
        <div class="video_box">
            <h2 class="center_horisontal">Katy Perry 1</h2>
                <div id="video_overlays">
                    <div id="outer" onclick="playPause()"><div id="inner">&nbsp;</div></div>
                </div>
                <video width="500" id="video1" controls>    
                <source src="Katy-Perry-swish.webm" type="video/webm">
            </video> 
            <!--Script til html-knapper til video-->
            <script> 
                var myVideo=document.getElementById("video1"); 
                //lytter efter "pause" og "play" og viser eller skjulder #video_overlays
                video1.addEventListener('play', videoPausePlayHandler, false);
                video1.addEventListener('pause', videoPausePlayHandler, false);
                function videoPausePlayHandler(e) {
                if (e.type == 'play') {$('#video_overlays').hide(); $('#icon-pause').show();  $('#icon-play').hide();$('#video-start-text').hide();
                    } 
                else if (e.type == 'pause') {
                    $('#video_overlays').show(); $('#icon-pause').hide(); $('#icon-play').show();
                    //hvis filmen har stået på pause i 20 minutter relaodes siden
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        location.reload(); 
                      },1200000);
                    }
                }
                // play/pause-knap funktion
                function playPause()
                    { 
                    if (myVideo.paused) 
                      myVideo.play(); 

                    else 
                      myVideo.pause(); 
                    } 
                //til starten af filmen og pause
                function rewind_and_pause()
                    { 
                    myVideo.currentTime=0;
                    myVideo.pause(); 
                    } 

            </script> 
        </div>
        <div class="video_box-2">
            <h2 class="center_horisontal">Katy Perry 2</h2>
                <div id="video_overlays2">
                    <div id="outer" onclick="playPause2()"><div id="inner">&nbsp;</div></div>
                </div>
                <video width="500" id="video2" controls>    
                <source src="Katy-Perry-bon.webm" type="video/webm">
            </video> 
            <!--Script til html-knapper til video-->
            <script> 
                var myVideo2=document.getElementById("video2"); 
                //lytter efter "pause" og "play" og viser eller skjulder #video_overlays
                video2.addEventListener('play', videoPausePlayHandler, false);
                video2.addEventListener('pause', videoPausePlayHandler, false);
                function videoPausePlayHandler(e) {
                if (e.type == 'play') {$('#video_overlays2').hide(); $('#icon-pause2').show();  $('#icon-play2').hide();$('#video-start-text').hide();
                    } 
                else if (e.type == 'pause') {
                    $('#video_overlays2').show(); $('#icon-pause2').hide(); $('#icon-play2').show();
                    //hvis filmen har stået på pause i 20 minutter relaodes siden
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        location.reload(); 
                      },1200000);
                    }
                }
                // play/pause-knap funktion
                function playPause2()
                    { 
                    if (myVideo2.paused) 
                      myVideo2.play(); 

                    else 
                      myVideo2.pause(); 
                    } 
                //til starten af filmen og pause
                function rewind_and_pause2()
                    { 
                    myVideo2.currentTime=0;
                    myVideo2.pause(); 
                    } 

            </script> 
        </div>
```

This is an example page with some seemingly unnecessary extra code that will be used in the final version (not about Katy Perry)

http://www.tilnorsk.com/katy/katy-perry.html

Thanks for your help :-)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have two functions with the same name, the second will rewrite the first declaration of `videoPausePlayHandler`.

That being said, you can simply add a global variable that will switch between the videos.

```
var currentVideo = true;
function videoPausePlayHandler(e) {
  /* pause all videos */
  if (videoSwitch) {
    /* play video one */
  } else {
    /* play video two */ 
  }
  videoSwitch = !videoSwitch;
};
```

Even better, you could use add class to the target element, this way you could handle more than two videos on the same page more easily and also could add some style. Go wild!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I did not get it to work, however, which has to do with my limited knowledge of JavaScript. I received this project that someone else started. As I understood from your answer, I renamed the second video's video